# It is possible to do a SMART report to an external USB HDD?

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, external-hdd

I have has installed Ubuntu/Debian too many times on it (five times), but for inexplicable reasons, it just stopped working and corrupt the files in it without intervention.

I don't know if it is an adapter issue, but I have realized at least two badblocks analysis and nothing wrong there.

The system stills working for at least four weeks.

The error can occur at runtime (disk just falls in a writing/reading mode), or at boot (just can't boot because the disk starts to fail sector-by-sector)

It's to note that I have been installed Debian 10 Stable, and I have no issues again (six months). It looks like a Ubuntu-only issue. Also, this week I had the opportunity to put my disk in a SATA, now I can see that the disk is moderately healthy, so probably was Ubuntu plus a micro/minimum that it can't treat that the major issue did occur.

It is possible to do a SMART report to an external USB HDD?

Comment: What are you actually asking?

Comment: "It is possible to do a SMART report to an external USB HDD?"

Answer (score 1):

Question is unclear; I will try to guess.

Exporting output of SMART to an external disk is possible, to save it for future use (but I don't understand why you would need this):

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1
smartctl -a /dev/sda >/mnt/sdb1/smart-sda.txt
```

If you want to SMART probe the USB disk, you want to read FROM USB, not TO USB; then, you tried

```
smartctl -a /dev/sdb
```

which failed with an error like

> /dev/sdb: Unknown USB bridge [0x2109:0x0715 (0xf040)] Please specify
> device type with the -d option.

which indicates the solution:

```
# smartctl -d help -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [armv7l-linux-4.13.16-sunxi] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

/dev/sdb: Unknown device type 'help'
=======> VALID ARGUMENTS ARE: ata, scsi, sat[,auto][,N][+TYPE], usbcypress[,X], usbjmicron[,p][,x][,N], usbsunplus, marvell, areca,N/E, 3ware,N, hpt,L/M/N, megaraid,N, aacraid,H,L,ID, cciss,N, auto, test <=======

# smartctl -d sat -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [armv7l-linux-4.13.16-sunxi] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital RE3 Serial ATA
[...]
```

if sat does not work, try all the other propositions you may have. Sat , usbcypress, usbjmicron, are frequent success; google for details. If none in your list works, you need to install a more recent distro. The list is machine dependant; -d help will show you what your current machine can use; detailed support depends on your machine, and for a given distro it may evolve with time.

Answer (score -1):

You can run a SMART check on any connected disk. You may need to install the `smartmontools` package, and then the command is `smartctl`. You can `man smartctl` to read its documentation.

Examples

```
smartctl -a /dev/sdb          # Report the SMART information from sdb
smartctl -t short /dev/sdb    # Run a short test on sdb
```